# Which one gets applied at the end?

Tags: html, css, wysiwyg

Which one gets applied at the end?

- CSS from external file
- inline CSS

I have racing situation in CSS style. I have give some style to some of the elements, but user has choice to edit them via WYSIWYG editor and for persistence reason I have to store those inline CSS which are generated by WYSIWYG inside database. So when user will render file again in browser which CSS will get applied at the end?

Comment: How about an example. What technologies/products etc.

Comment: There are very specific rules to which style gets applied, so there is _no_ race condition. Unless you have edge cases like both a `width` attribute _and_ a `width` style property, _and_ an older browser that doesn't know any better.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming equal specificity and no `!important` rules then there is no difference between a `<link>` and `<style>` element. They are just different syntaxes for including a stylesheet.

```
<link>          <!-- applied 1st --> 
<style></style> <!-- applied 2nd -->
<link>          <!-- applied 3rd -->
```

`style` **attributes** have, effectively, infinite specificity so get applied last (except for `!important` rules).

See also [The Cascade](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/cascade.html#cascade)

Comment: So it's basically the moment renderer renders a piece of syntax it applies those rules and moves ahead, Cool thanks!